# Do I have to hash twice in C#?

Tags: c#

I have code like the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    string Name;
    int NewInfo;
}

List<MyClass> newInfo = .... // initialize list with some values
Dictionary<string, int> myDict = .... // initialize dictionary with some values

foreach(var item in newInfo)
{
    if(myDict.ContainsKey(item.Name)) // 'A' I hash the first time here
         myDict[item.Name] += item.NewInfo // 'B' I hash the second (and third?) time here
    else
        myDict.Add(item.Name, item.NewInfo);
}
```

Is there any way to avoid doing two lookups in the Dictionary -- the first time to see if contains an entry, and the second time to update the value?  There may even be two hash lookups on line 'B' -- one to get the int value and another to update it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes - use `Dictionary.TryGetValue`. It takes an `out` parameter to receive the value, and returns whether or not the value was found. Here's your adjusted code:

```
foreach(var item in newInfo)
{
    int value;
    if (myDict.TryGetValue(item.Name, out value))
    {
        myDict[item.Name] = value + item.NewInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        myDict[item.Name] = item.NewInfo;
    }
}
```

However, we can do better than that **in this particular case**. If the key- *isn't* found, the `out` parameter is set to 0. As we're going to set the new value to either `item.NewInfo` or `item.NewInfo + value` we're really doing the same thing either way. We can ignore the return value of the method, and just use:

```
foreach(var item in newInfo)
{
    int value;
    myDict.TryGetValue(item.Name, out value);
    myDict[item.Name] = value + item.NewInfo;
}
```

That's quite unusual though - usually you *would* use the return value, obviously.

**Digression**

It's only because you're really doing a `GetValueOrDefault` operation that it works. In fact, that would be a valid pair of extension methods:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    TValue value;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value;
}

public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key,
     TValue customDefault)
{
    TValue value;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return customDefault;
    }
}
```

At that point you could make your code clear *and* concise:

```
foreach(var item in newInfo)
{
    myDict[item.Name] = myDict.GetValueOrDefault(item.Name) + item.NewInfo;
}
```

(You could call `GetValueOrDefault(item.Name, 0)` for potentially more clarity.)

**Back to the point...**

Note that you're still doing two lookups - one to fetch the value and one to add/replace it. You can't really avoid that without making the `TValue` type argument something mutable, which you could change in place. That would be possible, but not terribly nice.

In the original code, you're potentially doing *three* lookups - one for `ContainsKey`, and then two (if the key is found) to replace the value. It's easier to see that if we expand the `+=`:

```
myDict[item.Name] = myDict[item.Name] + item.NewInfo;
```

(`item.Name` would only be evaluated once, but other than that it's the same.)

**Another digression**

It would be good to have an operation on `Dictionary` which did a "lookup and replace" based on a function to get the new value based on the old one, e.g.

```
bool Update(TKey key, Func<TValue, bool, TValue> replacementFunction)
```

where `replacementFunction` would be a function taking the current value (or the default value of `TValue` if the key wasn't found) and a Boolean to say whether or not the key *was* actually found, and returns the new value. The dictionary could then look up the key, call the replacement function and update the value in place. (This one can't be implemented as an extension method.)

Comment: While this is functional, just be aware that value is only 0 because the default value for the int type is 0. From a defensive coding perspective, this sacrifices readability (and potentially maintainability) for succinctness. I'd stick with what you have, to be honest.

Comment: I'll give a bigger warning - it certainly is a special case.

Comment: Aren't you still hashing each item twice?  Once in TryGetValue, and again where you say 'myDict[item.Name]'?

Comment: Yes, he is, but the OP's code does it potentially three times.

Comment: Edited to make the three occurrences clearer. I'm getting quite fond of this answer now. If a two-liner gets accepted, I'll be miffed ;)

Comment: @Jon, now THAT looks good, especially considering the use of an extension method! +1 :)

Comment: @Adam: Out of interest, would you have implemented the "default default value" overload of GetValueOrDefault this way, or by calling dict.GetValueOrDefault(key, default(TValue))? I'm torn...

Comment: @Jon: Wouldn't they be identical? I don't think there's a way for dict to assign a value to the out variable without using default(T), is there? I think I would have done it as you have it in the code.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't both this:

foreach(var item in newInfo)
{
    int value;
    myDict.TryGetValue(item.Name, out value);
    myDict[item.Name] = value + item.NewInfo;
}

and this:

foreach(var item in newInfo)
{
    myDict[item.Name] = myDict.GetValueOrDefault(item.Name) + item.NewInfo;
}

throw an exception if item.Name was not in the Dictionary?

Comment: They would certainly behave exactly the same. I just wonder whether it would make it more readable.

Comment: @unknown: No, neither of them would TryGetValue doesn't throw an exception if the value isn't in the dictionary, so neither would GetValueOrDefault. The indexer doesn't throw an exception when you use it to *add* an entry, only when you try to *fetch* one where the key isn't present.

Comment: Seems to me that you are looking at it the wrong way. The problem is that you keep getting a refernce to a cell in the dictionary and then immeidately throw it away. A quick change to Dictionary<string, MyClass> and that all goes away.

Comment: I've added that extension method to my solution.  Do you think there is much performance overhead to using the extension method compared to the same algorithm 'inline'?

Comment: No, there should be no impact. Extension methods are just syntactic sugar that becomes a call to the static function on your static class and passes in your referenced instance as the 'this' parameter. Performance should be no different at runtime than if you had done this as a normal static function and passed in the instance yourself.

Comment: @GrauenWolf: I've mentioned that as an option. I like immutability where possible though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to hash twice most of the time. The secret is that you store an object in the dictionary instead of just an int.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newInfo = new List<MyClass>();
        var myDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

        foreach (var item in newInfo)
        {
            MyClass temp;
            if (!myDict.TryGetValue(item.Name, out temp))
            {
                temp = new MyClass() { Name = item.Name };
                myDict.Add(temp.Name,temp);
            }

            temp.NewInfo += 1;

        }

    }
}


class MyClass
{
    public string Name;
    public int NewInfo;
}
```

Comment: At least make them properties instead of public fields... ick! :)